# categorize every instance of an observation if one observation meets criteria

Tags: r, categorization

I have a database of company founders and their political donations. Many people give multiple times, but identify their jobs differently each time. Fortunately, each person's name is identified with a fixed numeric code.

I would like to be able to categorize each person as having a certain job if anywhere in the database they have indicated they have a certain type of job. Here is a replicable dataframe

```
name <- c("tom", "tom", "tom", "mary", "mary")
id <- c("123", "123", "123", "456", "456")
role <- c("investor", "company", "company", "company", "company")

df1 = data.frame(name, id, role)
```

The final dataframe I imagine would look like this, if I wanted to know if a person had identified themselves as an investor anywhere in the dataframe:

```
name <- c("tom", "tom", "tom", "mary", "mary")
id <- c("123", "123", "123", "456", "456")
role <- c("investor", "company", "company", "company", "company")
isinvestor <- c("yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no")

df1 = data.frame(name, id, role, isinvestor)
```

I've searched SO for tags like "conditional grouping" or "conditional categorization". Perhaps this is a common technique in computer science and i've just missed the term. Thank you for the help and let me know if I can make the question any easier to answer

Comment: The question is if you want to make many such columns for different job descriptions or you satisfied with just that one additional column `"isinvestor"`? For example, this column could be easily created by just `df1$isinvestor <- with(df1, ave(as.character(role), id, FUN = function(x) any(x == "investor")))`.

Comment: awesome! I'm not quite sure why that works, but it does! If there is a way to make it more general, that is, categorize every person with each type of job they've identified themselves with, that could be useful. For this, i think this solves my problem (though if your could explain you code a bit, that would be educational). Either way, feel free to post this as an answer and i'll vote it up!

Comment: The question is, what if the person gives different descriptions, which one you will pick? Also, how do you know which is a description and which is not? e.g., how do I know that `"company"` isn't a description?

Comment: oh, i see what you're asking. It all depends on what my hypothesis is and there are very few categories. In the database, people are a company, investor and maybe a few other types. So, it's easy to select by hand. In this case, I wanted to explore how investors give differently. But, i could see the usefulness in a more general way to categorize for columns with more unique values.

Comment: @tom For the general categorization, it would be useful to have some example with multiple categories.  A possible option using `data.table` is. `dcast(setDT(df1)[,  role1:=if(any(role!='company')) role[role!='company'] else role[1L], id][,ind:= 1:.N ,id], name+id+ind~role1, value.var='role1', length)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg i confess, i have no idea why using ave() works. it's an averaging function. if don't mind, care to explain? it's amazing in it's simplicity and i'm stumped

Comment: @akrun if it helps, you could add "company" and "investor" to the possible categories. in which case, the variable under "mary" would be TRUE. Or possibly, the last column would contain something like "Investor, Company" or each row of Tom and "Company" for each row of mary. is that what you're asking? seems like a promising direction

Comment: It is averaging function by it's default, but you can override the default function by using `FUN = ` (just like I did).

Comment: @tom Can you update your post with more categories and expected result  so that it will be helpful to crosscheck